# Is it possible to enforce database integrity based indirect relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have `Thing`s which have a `Type`. I also have these `Token`s that are associated to a `Type`. Now I want to say that a `Thing` has a combination of `Token`s. A possible table representation would be:

```
| Thing |  | Type |  | Token |  | TypeToken |  | ThingToken |
|-------|  |------|  |-------|  |-----------|  |------------|
| Id    |  | Id   |  | Id    |  | TypeId    |  | ThingId    |
| Type  |  |------|  |-------|  | TokenId   |  | TokenId    |
|-------|                       |-----------|  |------------|
```

For database integrity, I'd like to enforce that a `Thing` can only have `Token`s if they were previously associated to a `Type`. What would my be best option be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to add the TypeId to the ThingToken table so you can use it in foreign keys.  You also need an additional unique constraint on Thing, but you can put it on (TypeId,Id) so it's also useful for lookups by TypeId, and is physically identical to a nonclustered index on just (TypeId).

EG:

```
use tempdb
go

drop table if exists ThingToken
drop table if exists TypeToken
drop table if exists Token
drop table if exists Thing
drop table if exists Type
--| Thing |  | Type |  | Token |  | TypeToken |  | ThingToken |
--|-------|  |------|  |-------|  |-----------|  |------------|
--| Id    |  | Id   |  | Id    |  | TypeId    |  | ThingId    |
--| Type  |  |------|  |-------|  | TokenId   |  | TokenId    |
--|-------|                       |-----------|  |------------|

create table Type(Id int primary key)
create table Token(Id int primary key)
create table TypeToken
(
  TypeId int not null references Type, 
  TokenId int not null references Token,
  constraint pk_TypeToken
    primary key (TypeId,TokenId)
)

create table Thing
(
  Id int not null primary key, 
  TypeId int references Type,
  constraint ak_Thing
    unique (TypeId,Id)
)

create table ThingToken
(
  ThingId int not null,
  TokenId int not null,
  TypeId int not null,
  constraint pk_ThingToken 
     primary key (ThingId,TokenId),
  constraint fk_ThingToken_Thing 
    foreign key (TypeId,ThingId) references Thing(TypeId, Id),
  constraint fk_ThingToken_TypeToken 
    foreign key (TypeId,TokenId) references TypeToken(TypeId, TokenId)
)
```

Comment: This is the kind of solution I'm looking for, but now I'm wondering: won't having TypeId in ThingToken break normalization rules, since it is obtainable from ThingId?

Comment: @Olivetree (1/2): True, due to `FD {ThingId} -> {TypeId}` table `ThingToken {ThingId, TokenId, TypeId}` having `PK {ThingId, TokenId}` is *not* in `2NF`. However, logical errors due to introduced redundancy are prevented by `FK {ThingId, TypeId}` to table `Thing`, and your business rules are enforced, hence all is good.

Comment: @Olivetree (2/2): Practical SQL often requires this type of compromise due to lack of assertions, db-wide constraints. @David is using `FK` constraints for something that normally would have be done by assertions, if we had them. Bottom line, the objective of normalization is to *prevent and remove logical errors* from a DB, so all is good here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! Here is a example what you need,

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    FooId INT
,   Value VARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE Bar (
    BarId INT
,   FooId INT
,   Value VARCHAR(10)
)
GO
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFooExistsOnBar
(
    @FooId INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Response BIT = 0;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE FooId = @FooId)
        SET @Response = 1;

    RETURN @Response
END
GO

ALTER TABLE Foo
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_FooId_Foo
CHECK (dbo.CheckFooExistsOnBar(FooId) = 1)

INSERT INTO Foo (FooId, Value) VALUES (1, '')
```

[image: Excpt]

Check out [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: For very few rows, this would work. But I doubt I would be advisable to try inserting 1m rows and check the constraint 1 million times row by row.

Comment: I agree definitely, that shows only what is the solution. My personal mind is which any validations should not do at the database layer because of performance affect. Thanks for your notice. @LuisLL

Comment: Would the integrity still be kept in case the TypeToken table data changed such that a previously assigned Token to a Thing would no longer be possible?
(I realized the title mentioned "insert", I fixed it now)

Comment: Unfortunately :( Above script can't, but triggers can check to bi directional validation.